# Is it possible to change the UI/behavior of the "Keyboard" button when in camera mode?

Tags: card.io

For example, instead of going to manual entry, simply go back to the previous page. I know it is possible to completely remove the button with the EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY option but I'm looking for a way to modify the button.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the functionality you're looking for is not available.